# Two column jQuery.sortable list with an order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have tried and failed several ways to make this work and I feel like providing an example wouldn't do any good.

What I am trying to do is have a two column sortable list. On the left is a number of items. On the right is an empty list with the same number of placeholders. When I drag an item onto the right column, I would like to take the place of the placeholders.

Essentially, I am providing a randomized list on the left and asking them to sort it by dragging it to the list on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sortable widget is a combination of draggable and droppable, i'd suggest using them directly because you don't really need the sortable functionality. All you need is to have draggable items and droppable targets, then on drop, replace the droppable target with the draggable item and make it no longer draggable.